# MySQLi config php.ini on CentOS 7 - Moodle installation

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, moodle

I am trying to install Moodle 3.0 on my CentOS 7 server, I got the error message:

"PHP has not been properly configured with the MySQLi extension for it to communicate with MySQL. Please check your php.ini file or recompile PHP".

Opened the php.ini file but not sure exactly what line to change/uncomment. I know on Windows machines the line extension=php_mysqli.dll should be uncommented to fix this. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `yum install php-mysqli` perhaps?

Comment: yum install php-mysqli installs fine but I still get the error on how to configure the php.ini file to support mysqli